# MySQL SELECT Minutes between two dates (DIFFERENT DAYS)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am getting really frustrated with this MySQL statement today, aha.

So I need to find the amount of minutes between when the volunteer clocked in, vs when they clocked out.

In the volunteer_timeclock table if I set the datetime of the Clock_In to the same DAY as the Clock_Out, I can get any time function to work (TIMEDIFF, etc.) however... If the clock out day is the following day(For example if I clocked in at 2020-04-26 12:00:00, and clocked out at 2020-04-27 12:00:00) the following code should return 1440 since it would be 60 * 24, but it doesn't return any records at all.

Here is the statement I am using:

```
SELECT 
          A1.volunteer_id, 
          A1.datetime AS check_in_at, 
          A2.datetime AS check_out_at,
          ROUND(time_to_sec((TIMEDIFF(A2.datetime, A1.datetime))) / 60) AS total_time
          FROM 
          volunteer_timeclock AS A1 
          INNER JOIN volunteer_timeclock AS A2 
          ON A1.volunteer_id = A2.volunteer_id 
          AND DATE(A1.datetime) = DATE(A2.datetime) 
          WHERE A1.status = 'clock_in' 
          AND A2.status = 'clock_out' 
          AND DATE(A1.datetime) BETWEEN '2020-01-1' 
          AND '2020-12-31'
          AND DATE(A2.datetime) BETWEEN '2020-01-1' 
          AND '2020-12-31'
          AND A1.volunteer_id = '25'
          ORDER BY A1.datetime DESC
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TIME` values are inherently limited in their range.  Convert the `datetimes` to seconds directly.  That also simplifies the logic:

```
(TO_SECONDS(A2.datetime) - TO_SECONDS(A1.datetime)) / 60)
```

Comment: I appreciate the quick response. I tried this as well, it still results in no rows being returned if the date is on the next day.

Comment: Nevermind. It was a fault of my AND statement, I will use this however to avoid limitations.

Answer (score 0):

Right. I feel like an idiot, I had an AND statement saying the DATE had to be the same. Thanks for the replies.

Comment: You can always delete the question